# ShallowCompare not working with immutable js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Immutable js in my react app! As a part of optimization, I tried using shallowCompare in shouldComponentUpdate and that's when I found out that shallowCompare returns true for unchanged state and props! I have a path and module key in my props which are immutable objects ( list and map respectively! ) I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong or shallowCompare doesn't support immutable js, Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, `shallowCompare` works perfectly fine with immutable objects.

If you want special support for [Immutable.is()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is), you can use [shallowEqualImmutable](https://github.com/jurassix/react-immutable-render-mixin). It understands Immutable collections better, as it considers lists of the same values to be the same.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallowEqualImmutable } from 'react-immutable-render-mixin';
class Test extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !shallowEqualImmutable(this.props, nextProps) ||
           !shallowEqualImmutable(this.state, nextState);  
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```